# Google Cardboard controlling PC

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

When I saw the Google Cardboard for Unity, I assumed this meant that you would be able to make a Unity PC game and use your phone as a screen/controller. All I can see is it wanting me to make an android app which is all well and good, but it doesn't allow for input from the keyboard.

Is there a way to stream the Unity PC project to the device and retrieve input (i.e. Headtracking, NFC magnet)?

Comment: I've been thinking about the same thing. Steam has In-Home streaming, Xbox has something similar. It would let us use much more powerful hardware to render the frames, but would perhaps add a bit of latency? I bet this will turn up soon enough, not everyone will afford Oculus Rift. Many Android phones should have good enough sensors and screens.

Comment: @pcguru actually not really. For example, phone displays tend to be fell persistance displays, that lend themselves to the judder effect, greatly decreasing image sharpness while in movement. Sequential RGB displays can create color problems when moving your head, and your head moves really fast when turning. There is also the problem with screen resolution. For a normal phone 2kx1k is plenty, because it takes up a low % of your total field of view. But when put in a headset, that same resolution needs to cover a really big portion of your FOV. VR done right is actually very hard ;)

Comment: Yeah the definition of "done right" is key. The perfect vr helmet will never be built. But rendering on a PC would still be a big step forward compared to the puny performance cellphones provide. Perfect? Definitely not, but definitely more immersive and realistic than the demos available for cardboard now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with such a solution is latency. In VR latency is a big deal. The overall latency from input to photons reaching your eyes should be 20ms or lower. Regular games have 30-60 ms latency by themselves. Add to that the gyro latency, the phone display latency... If you want to add another 25ms or more ping to your VR experience, that's gonna be painful and may even make you sick. If you want to read more on why latency is such a big deal in VR, Michael Abrash wrote an excellend blogpost about it: [post on latency](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/abrash/latency-the-sine-qua-non-of-ar-and-vr/)

If you want to necessairly use a keyboard for navigation, consider using a bluetooth keyboard that can be used with android devices. Also keep in mind that with the current technology, especially without a dedicated headset, really dynamic vr experiences probably won't work very well and can make some people uncomfortable or sick. For a good read on designign virtual reality experiences, please refer to this guide from the Oculus Rift: http://static.oculus.com/sdk-downloads/documents/Oculus_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf

Comment: If the phone is able to push a mere 20 fps, the 20-30 ms network latency is compensated for if the computer can pump 60 fps instead. Obviously neither scenario is great, but the improved image quality with the same latency should be prefferable?

Comment: If you have 20 fps then you have a very low framerate for a Virtual Reality experience. But the network ping is a big differrence. Remember that it is multiplied by 2 - once to get the sensor data to your pc, and next to get the frame from your pc to your phone. Your head turns 100 degrees a second and thats a quite easy tempo, it can move faster. If the image is 60ms "behind" your head rotation, everything will be displaced by six degrees. That is VERY noticable, especially at bigger distances within the game. And that is the web lag alone! Your brain is trained to detect such abnormalities.

Comment: @pcguru Thats why I would advise reducing the scenes polygon count etc and increase the framerate on the phone. I guess you can try to design your experience around not moving your head too much or too fast, and I agree that there may be no "good" solution to these problems at the moment. People might even not notice these issues on a concious level, but some of them may feel discomfort or even nausea using your game, and they wont be able to tell why. Heck, my first walk around a Japanese garden in Oculus Rift DK2 left me a little dizzy after a few minutes and I had to het used to it.

Comment: A better solution might be to stream the HD video and headtracking over a USB tether. Wifi may have problems keeping up the frame rate in HD.
Most phone screens are not really HD yet (VR cuts the resolution in half).
4K phones are on the way with nextgen USB, so direct tethering may always be better (Oculus already tethers to PC).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the Cardboard SDK for talking with a PC-hosted Unity game.  You could adapt the code from the Unity Remote 4 project:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18106

Answer (score 0):

We are developing the app what you want except it uses GearVR instead of Cardboard. Please check the link below.

http://challengepost.com/software/airvr

Answer (score 0):

Streaming from your PC to your phone's Cardboard is possible using third-party apps, such as [Trinus VR](http://trinusvr.com/) (the client app on your phone) and [Vireio](http://www.mtbs3d.com/new-vireio-site) (the streaming app on your computer). The two apps will then communicate via your home network (Wi-Fi or other) to stream the images.